# How to add location to tweet in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, twitter, social-framework

I'm using the Social Framework to be able to share content from my app to Twitter. I'd like to be able to add a location to the tweet. Here's my code:

```
if SLComposeViewController.isAvailableForServiceType(SLServiceTypeTwitter) {
  let twitterComposeVC = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeTwitter)   
  twitterComposeVC.setInitialText("I found a really nice spot. Check it out here")          
  self.presentViewController(twitterComposeVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
} else {
  self.showAlertMessage("Please make sure you're logged into Twitter in your device settings")
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no option to add location to your Tweet using `SLComposeViewController`, a user has to set it explicitly. You will have to create a custom tweet sheet.

There are libraries that do this (e.g. [LGTweeter](https://github.com/lewisgodowski/LGTweeter)) but I haven't found any written in Swift (but you can use objective-c libraries in you Swift code).

**UPDATE:**

The LGTweeter has been removed from the GitHub, it can be found on the [CocoaPods](http://cocoapods.org/pods/LGTweeter), but it seems that it'is no longer being developed.